# Запись звука в android

Tags: java, android

Я новичок в этом деле, но может кто подскажет есть ли возможность записи звука в Android, чтобы не использовать MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC или вообще отойти от MediaRecorder.AudioSource. Наверняка должно что-то быть. Ну или есть ли возможность просмотреть каким-то образом все устройства, в том числе и записи, чтобы из них можно было бы выбрать.

Comment: android studio - это среда разработки и к записи звуков в системе андроид имеет весьма далёкое отношение (знает синтаксис связанных с этим классов и методов)

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю. Видно, что и вы поняли, что пишу приложение в среде Android Studio. А учитывая, что я только начал в ней разбираться, то и спросил у уже знающих и опытных людей, есть ли какая библиотека (родная или сторонняя, кроме MediaRecorder.AudioSource ), чтобы постараться найти микрофоны в Android-приставке.

Comment: для вашего вопроса совершенно не важно, в какой именно среде вы его пишите. андроид студио не обладает никакой особой силой по сравнению с другими средами разработки под андроид, чтобы ее упоминание могло решить проблему по особенному

Comment: Прошу извинение за хамство, но демагогия отвлекает. Был задан конкретный вопрос и просьба совета от знающих людей. А именно "есть ли возможность просмотреть каким-то образом все устройства, в том числе и записи, чтобы из них можно было бы выбрать на андроид устройстве и что-то с ними делать". То что вы пытаетесь показать свои знания, то это замечательно, но если не можете подсказать советом в программировании под андроид, то прошу не отвлекайте.